# I want to join table but this is show error message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

so this is the error message

> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.823 s
>   <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.test1.test1.Test1ApplicationTests
>   contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition
>   on
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
>   [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration]
>   from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@42a57993] Caused
>   by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/PhysicalNamingStrategy Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy

This is My Code , so i want to join column OrderTransaction Based on customer_id

this is my orderRepository

```
    public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository <Customer, Long> {
        @Modifying
        @Query(value ="SELECT ordertransactions.id, Customer.name" +
    "FROM ordertransactions" +
    "INNER JOIN Customer ON orderransactions.id = customer.id;" ,nativeQuery = true)
        int deleteCustomer(Customer Customer); 

    //    @Query(value="select c from customer where c.name=:nama_customer")
    //    Customer findCustomerByName(@Param("namaCustomer")String nama);
        @Query(value="SELECT name, city FROM Customer")
        Customer findCustomerByName(@Param("nameCustomer")String name);
}
```

this is my customerModel

```
@Entity
 @Table(name= "Customer")
// @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Customer {

//
    public Customer(Long customer_id, String Name, Integer Phone , String stock , String city) {
        this.customer_id = customer_id;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Phone = Phone;
        this.stock = stock;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Long getCustomer_id() {
        return customer_id;
    }

    public void setCustomer_id(Long customer_id) {
        this.customer_id = customer_id;
    }

    public Customer() {
    }

//    public Customer(String string) {
//        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
//    }

//    public Customer(Long orderId, Long id, String name, Integer phone, String stock, String city) {
//        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
//    }



    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public Integer getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(Integer Phone) {
        this.Phone = Phone;
    }

    public String getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(String stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }


    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long customer_id;

     @Column(name="name",nullable=false)
     private String Name;

     @Column(name="phone",nullable=false)
     private Integer Phone;


     @Column(name="stock",nullable=false)
     private String stock;

     @Column(name="city",nullable=false)
     private String city;


}
```

this is my orderTransaction Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "ordertransactions")
public class OrderTransaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="order_name",nullable = false)
    private String OrderName;

    @OneToMany
     @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = true,nullable = false)
//     @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = true,nullable = false)
     private Customer customer;


    public OrderTransaction(Long id, String OrderName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.OrderName = OrderName;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getOrderName() {
        return OrderName;
    }

    public void setOrderName(String OrderName) {
        this.OrderName = OrderName;
    }


}
```

Comment: Check that you do not have multiple versions of Hibernate on the runtime classpath.

Answer (score 0):

It seem you are missing "hibernate-core-5.x.jar" in classpath.